# How can I get the daterange picker to return the value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, semantic-ui-react

I am trying to create a simple date range picker that will be used to pass the date from the drop-down to a sql query right now I just want to handle it and pass it to return an h1 tag with the value picked. Today | Last 7 Days ect. If your help includes the conversion with moment js that would be a bonus. Here is my code 
And Here is a link to a codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/gotrax-daterange-95u2j?fontsize=14

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Header, Menu, Dropdown, Icon, Button } from "semantic-ui-react";
import moment from "moment";
import "semantic-ui/dist/semantic.min.css";

export default class DatePicker extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      date: "",
      wasSubmitted: false,
      dateRange: [
        { key: "Today", text: "Today", value: `${moment()}` },
        { key: "Yesterday", text: "Yesterday", value: "yesterday" },
        { key: "Last 7 Days", text: "Last 7 Days", value: "last 7 days" },
        { key: "Last 30 Days", text: "Last 30 Days", value: "last 30 days" },
        { key: "This Month", text: "This Month", value: "this month" },
        { key: "Last Month", text: "Last Month", value: "last month" },
        { key: "Custom Range", text: "Custom Range", value: "custom range" }
      ]
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }
  handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ wasSubmitted: true });
    console.log(this.state.dateRange);
  };

  handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      date: e._d
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { date, wasSubmitted } = this.state;
    return (
      <>
      {!wasSubmitted && (
      <div>
        <div>
          <Menu secondary borderless={true} fluid={true}>
            <Menu.Item>
              <Header>Date Range:</Header>
            </Menu.Item>
            <Menu.Item className="width15em">
              <Icon name="calendar" />
              <Dropdown
                placeholder="Pick Date Range"
                options={this.state.dateRange}
              />
            </Menu.Item>
            <Menu.Menu position="right" borderless={true}>
              <Menu.Item>
                <Button
                  primary
                  size="small"
                  onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
                  type="submit"
                  value={this.state.dateRange}
                  onChange={this.handleChange}
                >
                  Update
                </Button>
              </Menu.Item>
              <Menu.Item>
                <Button color="green" size="small">
                  Export CSV
                </Button>
              </Menu.Item>
            </Menu.Menu>
          </Menu>
        </div>
      </div>
      )}
      </>
    );
  }
}
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<DatePicker />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question a little better I calculated the dates, for the custom date range you need a date range picker something like https://react-day-picker.js.org/examples/selected-range/

I also added a form with the onSubmit so that update `console.logs` what you wanted.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Header, Menu, Dropdown, Icon, Button } from "semantic-ui-react";
import moment from "moment";
import "semantic-ui/dist/semantic.min.css";

export default class DatePicker extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      date: "",
      wasSubmitted: false,
      dateRange: [
        {
          key: "Today",
          text: "Today",
          value: {
            start: moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
            end: moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD")
          }
        },
        {
          key: "Yesterday",
          text: "Yesterday",
          value: {
            start: moment()
              .subtract(1, "d")
              .format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
            end: moment()
              .subtract(1, "d")
              .format("YYYY-MM-DD")
          }
        },
        {
          key: "Last 7 Days",
          text: "Last 7 Days",
          value: {
            start: moment()
              .subtract(7, "d")
              .format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
            end: moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD")
          }
        },
        {
          key: "Last 30 Days",
          text: "Last 30 Days",
          value: {
            start: moment()
              .subtract(30, "d")
              .format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
            end: moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD")
          }
        },
        {
          key: "This Month",
          text: "This Month",
          value: {
            start: moment()
              .startOf("month")
              .format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
            end: moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD")
          }
        },
        {
          key: "Last Month",
          text: "Last Month",
          value: {
            start: moment()
              .subtract(1, "month")
              .startOf("month")
              .format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
            end: moment()
              .subtract(1, "month")
              .endOf("month")
              .format("YYYY-MM-DD")
          }
        },
        { key: "Custom Range", text: "Custom Range", value: "custom range" }
      ]
    };
    // this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    // this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }
  handleSubmit = event => {
    console.log(this.state.date);
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ wasSubmitted: true });
  };

  handleChange = (e, d) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.persist();
    this.setState({
      date: d.value
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { date, wasSubmitted } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <Menu secondary borderless={true} fluid={true}>
            <Menu.Item>
              <Header>Date Range:</Header>
            </Menu.Item>
            <Menu.Item className="width15em">
              <Icon name="calendar" />
              <Dropdown
                placeholder="Pick Date Range"
                options={this.state.dateRange}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
              />
            </Menu.Item>
            <Menu.Menu position="right" borderless="true">
              <Menu.Item>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                  <Button
                    primary
                    size="small"
                    onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
                    type="submit"
                    value={this.state.date}
                  >
                    Update
                  </Button>
                </form>
              </Menu.Item>
              <Menu.Item>
                <Button color="green" size="small">
                  Export CSV
                </Button>
              </Menu.Item>
            </Menu.Menu>
          </Menu>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<DatePicker />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have given a try. I don't understand what does it mean this month (is it range?) For custom range you need to add proper calculator or input box:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Header, Menu, Dropdown, Icon, Button } from "semantic-ui-react";
import moment from "moment";
import "semantic-ui/dist/semantic.min.css";

export default class DatePicker extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      date: "",
      wasSubmitted: false,
      dateRange: [ //Added moment formatting
        { key: "Today", text: "Today", value: moment().subtract(7,'d').format('YYYY-MM-DD') },
        { key: "Yesterday", text: "Yesterday", value: moment().subtract(1,'d').format('YYYY-MM-DD') },
        { key: "Last 7 Days", text: "Last 7 Days", value: moment().subtract(7,'d').format('YYYY-MM-DD') },
        { key: "Last 30 Days", text: "Last 30 Days", value: moment().subtract(30,'d').format('YYYY-MM-DD') },
        { key: "This Month", text: "This Month", value: "this month" },
        { key: "Last Month", text: "Last Month", value: moment().subtract(1,'months').format('YYYY-MM-DD') },
        { key: "Custom Range", text: "Custom Range", value: "custom range" } //You need to add custom input and the moment pattern would be same
      ]
    };
    // this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    // this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }
  handleSubmit = event => {
    console.log(this.state.dateRange);
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ wasSubmitted: true });
    
  };

  handleChange = (e,d) => { //from semantic documentation second argument is data
    e.preventDefault();
    e.persist()
    this.setState({
      date: d.value
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { date, wasSubmitted } = this.state;
    console.log(date)
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <Menu secondary borderless={true} fluid={true}>
            <Menu.Item>
              <Header>Date Range:</Header>
            </Menu.Item>
            <Menu.Item className="width15em">
              <Icon name="calendar" />
              <Dropdown
                placeholder="Pick Date Range"
                options={this.state.dateRange}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
              />
            </Menu.Item>
            <Menu.Menu position="right" borderless={true}>
              <Menu.Item>
                <Button
                  primary
                  size="small"
                  onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
                  type="submit"
                  value={this.state.dateRange}
                >
                  Update
                </Button>
              </Menu.Item>
              <Menu.Item>
                <Button color="green" size="small">
                  Export CSV
                </Button>
              </Menu.Item>
            </Menu.Menu>
          </Menu>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<DatePicker />, rootElement);
```

Demo Link : https://codesandbox.io/s/gotrax-daterange-h0rv1

Comment: Yes its supposed to be a rang this month is from today till the last 30 calendar days. Last month is starting from the 30 days from today and all the days. ie. this month is 2019-10-31 till 2019-10-01 and last 7 days is a range and then last month is 2019-09-01 to 2019-09-30 Thanks a lot for your answer

Comment: Also your answer is not linking it to the update button instead its just `console.log(date)` While I do like this answer for the robust effort added to the state with moment its partial and not whole.